# Android Webview with a toggle button

Tags: android, webview, togglebutton

I have two  overlapping webviews with in a frame layout. One contains a map and the other (on top of the map) contains the details. I want to let user to on and off the webview contains details with a toggle button. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

For Toggle Button simply you have to use:

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOn="@string/toggle_turn_on"
        android:textOff="@string/toggle_turn_off"
        android:checked="true" />
```

Now, you have ID for toggle. Start work on MainActivity.

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {

    ToggleButton toggleButton2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
    Button btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

    btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
           result.append("\ntoggleButton2 : ").append(toggleButton2.getText());

           Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this, result.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });
```

For Instance have a look there, if toogle is ON that would display like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I want to display the second web view (on top of the first web view) when you turn on the toggle button not a toast.

Answer (score 0):

First get the value of your switch button and check what is user prefer to do.

```
String val= (String)  (switchVal.isChecked()?  switchVal.getTextOn() : switchVal.getTextOff());
```

If he selected to be off the detail view then set not to be visible ([setKeepScreenOn(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setKeepScreenOn%28boolean%29)) your detail webview.